# Export multiple datasets to multiple sheets(Imp: excluding variable name/label in datasets)

Tags: sas

I have few datasets which i have to export to excel.

For example: 
dataset: ds1

**Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3**

datax    datay         dataz

dataset: ds2

**Variable_A Variable_B Variable_X**

dataxxx     datayyy   datazzz

Requirement:

Export these datasets to excel sheet with out variable names/labels. 
example excel sheet should look like:
datax datay dataz

i.e., with out variable names/labels and only data.

I tried using proc export with dbms as csv

```
proc export data=ds1
dbms=csv
outfile="ds1_data.csv"
replace;
putnames=NO;
run;

proc export data=ds2
dbms=csv
outfile="ds2_data.csv"
replace;
putnames=NO;
run;
```

It is working fine with putnames="No" option.

However this creates multiple csv files.
I need a single excel sheet with multiple sheets (with out variable names)

Any options available?

Comment: You can't use CSV to write a multisheet anything, CSV has no sheet concept.  If you want an excel file, you have to use DBMS=EXCEL or XLS or XLSX, or an ODS variation.

Comment: @Joe. Thanks! I tried Tagsets.ExcelXp and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

@Kay 
You can write this way.

```
proc export data=ds1
dbms=xls
outfile="ds1_data.xls"
replace;
putnames=NO;
sheet=ds1;
run;

proc export data=ds2
dbms=xls
outfile="ds1_data.xls"
replace;
putnames=NO;
sheet=ds2;
run;
```

Give the sheet name and, change the dbms to xls and give the same location for the file to have more than one datasets in the same excel workbook. 
Sheet= option might not work when DBMS = csv if I am not wrong.

Comment: Hi. Thanks! When i try this method, I am not getting the final excel in proper format. Some data is going blank. Have to find the reason.  I tried using Tagses.ExcelXp and it is working fine.